# compound key in ebean and play framework

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

I've just started using Play Framework. After I finished tutorials (covering basic functions) I try setup connection between database and play. One of my relations has schema:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop`.`CatPath` (
  `parentC` INT NOT NULL ,
  `childC` INT NOT NULL ,
  `depth` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parentC`, `childC`) 
  )
```

so I built model's class:

```
@Entity
public class CatPath extends Model {

@EmbeddedId 
public CatPathKey key;
public Long depth;

public class CatPathKey {

        public Long parentC;
        public Long childC;
}   

public static Finder<CatPathKey, CatPath> find = new Finder<CatPathKey, CatPath>(CatPathKey.class, CatPath.class);
```

after compilation I get exception:

```
PersistenceException: Could not find BeanDescriptor for class models.CatPath$KatPathKey. Perhaps the EmbeddedId class is not registered?
```

I don't know where is a problem, when I followed tutorials everything worked. Only difference between my code and tutorial's is key: I have compound key, in tutorials only one column makes key. Why in tutorials 'registering class' wasn't necessary? I guess, it was registered automatically but why now, with compound key, it isn't?

I tried to find some information, I found: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Ids/EmbeddedId
this xml code is 'class registering'? In Play framework tutorials and  detailed topics xml isn't mentioned, I didn't do anything with my model's classes and everything worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add the `@Embeddable` annotation under your `CatPathKey` class:

```
@Embeddable
public class CatPathKey {

        public Long parentC;
        public Long childC;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works perfectly. Could you explain why I didn't get exception with single primary key?

Comment: The `@Embeddable` annotation is used by ebean to register your class. If you use a single primary key, it works since the containaing class has been registered using the `@Entity` annotation.

Comment: Is it possible to have two ManyToOne fields in Embeddable class? I need a composite key to make sure that I have only unique DB entry referencing two other entries.