# Compound key with Ebean and PlayFramework

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I have created a compound key in MySQL. The table is `ActionNoteCode` and the compound key consists of the fields `action_note_code` and `collection`. I followed the example at [compound key in ebean and play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030937/compound-key-in-ebean-and-play-framework).

The class `ActionNoteCode` code:

```
@Entity
public class ActionNoteCode extends Model {
    @EmbeddedId
    public ActionNoteCodeIndex id;
    String description = "";

    @Embeddable
    class ActionNoteCodeIndex {
        String acvtion_note_code;
        String collection;
    }
}
```

When Play starts it throws the following error:

```
Cannot register class [models.prospector.actionNote.ActionNoteCode$ActionNoteCodeIndex] in Ebean server
```

This shows that you are using the models folder/package:

```
ebean.default="models.*"
```

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot register class [models.prospector.actionNote.ActionNoteCode$ActionNoteCodeIndex] in Ebean server]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:156)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:809)
    at play.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.java:368)
    at play.db.ebean.DefaultEbeanConfig$EbeanConfigParser.addModelClassesToServerConfig(DefaultEbeanConfig.java:107)
    at play.db.ebean.DefaultEbeanConfig$EbeanConfigParser.parse(DefaultEbeanConfig.java:82)
    at play.db.ebean.DefaultEbeanConfig$EbeanConfigParser.get(DefaultEbeanConfig.java:56)
    at play.db.ebean.DefaultEbeanConfig$EbeanConfigParser.get(DefaultEbeanConfig.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
Location:
models/prospector/actionNote/ActionNoteCode$ActionNoteCodeIndex.<init>(Lmodels/prospector/actionNote/ActionNoteCode;)V @2: invokevirtual
Reason:
  Type uninitializedThis (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'models/prospector/actionNote/ActionNoteCode$ActionNoteCodeIndex'
Current Frame:
bci: @2
flags: { flagThisUninit }
locals: { uninitializedThis, 'models/prospector/actionNote/ActionNoteCode' }
stack: { uninitializedThis, 'models/prospector/actionNote/ActionNoteCode' }
Bytecode:
0x0000000: 2a2b b600 202a b700 232a bb00 2559 2ab7
0x0000010: 0028 b500 2ab1                         
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at play.db.ebean.DefaultEbeanConfig$EbeanConfigParser.addModelClassesToServerConfig(DefaultEbeanConfig.java:105)
    at play.db.ebean.DefaultEbeanConfig$EbeanConfigParser.parse(DefaultEbeanConfig.java:82)
    at play.db.ebean.DefaultEbeanConfig$EbeanConfigParser.get(DefaultEbeanConfig.java:56)
    at play.db.ebean.DefaultEbeanConfig$EbeanConfigParser.get(DefaultEbeanConfig.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
```

Comment: Here is the complete stack trace..

Comment: try to make your class static,`public static class ActionNoteCodeIndex`

Answer (score 0):

1- Try to make your class static, `public static class ActionNoteCodeIndex`.

2 - If it does not work, move you class `ActionNoteCodeIndex` to a separated file. I guess it does make a difference because ebean scans the files in order to use them.